# Changing database Engine

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, database-migration

We have a table that uses full text searches and so is required to use the MyISAM engine:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `netyears`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `netyears` (
  `PK_NETYEARID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ITEMNAME` varchar(9) default NULL,
  `ISLIVE` char(1) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`PK_NETYEARID`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `ITEMNAME` (`ITEMNAME`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

Now I'm trying to implement a mysql cluster of 5 machines to see the performance benefits (1 management node, two daemon nodes and two data nodes following this [tutorial](http://blog.secaserver.com/2012/11/centos-6-install-mysql-cluster-the-simple-way/))

My question: What are the considerations I need to take into account knowing that I'm switching from the MyISAM engine to the NDB (required for consistency across clustered nodes) engine?

**As a side note**, after browsing through pretty much all the SQL used on the above table, the `MATCH` or `AGAINST` keywords are not used. Does this mean the fulltext search being implemented was pointless?

Comment: First consideration that you have is that NDB engine doesn't support fulltext indexes.

Comment: In reply to the side note: yes, you're not actually ever using fulltext search.

Answer (score 0):

Some considerations are that the `NDB` engine does not support fulltext (`MyISAM` and `InnoDB` are the only enginse that do) searches, so you wont be able to use `MATCH` / `AGAINST` but that shouldn't be a problem since you don't have these statements in your `SQL`, and yes since you don't have them it means that you just need to switch the engine and dump/import your data to your cluster with the new `NDB` engine.

Comment: Notice: Since MySQL 5.6 InnoDB also supports full text indexes and search.